# É errado usar o atributo position pra posicionar elementos, em vez do float?

Tags: html, css

É errado usar o atributo position pra posicionar elementos na página, em vez do float ? Se sim, porque ?

Comment: Errado pra que? Se fosse errado não existira.

Comment: Li na internet que o position deve ser usado apenas pra pequenas alterações na pagina, e pra definir os elementos dentro do layout era pra usar float

Comment: O float inicialmente foi projetado para alocar textos ao redor de imagens dando assim um efeito flutuante, porém ao longo do tempo foi se adaptando para o layout relativo, pode-se dizer que é um bom método, mas os outros também tem a sua importância e podem ser usados, inclusive recomendo o uso das flex-box para posicionar os elementos na página, hoje é o método mais completo, e não se usa float.

Comment: Mata a responsividade ... o efeito de Xpixel em um monitor full HD é bem diferente do efeito em um smartphone.

Answer (score 1):

Se todo o conteúdo da sua página for estático, não vejo problema em usar `position` para montar a estrutura. Se não for estático dificilmente você vai conseguir estruturar corretamente sem `float`.